# HTTP Server using Python Socket and multiple requests from one client

Tags: python, http, sockets, httpserver

I'm creating a HTTP server using python socket following this common technique:
https://emalsha.wordpress.com/2016/11/22/how-create-http-server-using-python-socket/ https://emalsha.wordpress.com/2016/11/24/how-create-http-server-using-python-socket-part-ii/
I want to send multiple request to GET .html file, .css file, and .png/.jmg ,... from the same connection. My .html file links to .css file and image files as well, the problem is that when a socket connection (with a port) GET a .html file (this is when I enter ,for example, 127.0.0.1:8082 on the browser), After that, this socket (port) didn't send any GET request for other files. Instead, the while loop start again and the line "connection,address = my_socket.accept()" create a new socket connection (port), and only after this connection(port) is created, it can send request to GET .css file, not the first one. And this process keep going on if I want to GET or POST.

I try to add the header "Connection: keep-alive" and "Content-Length: ..." in the response to client and of course in the GET method in client's request also has "Connection: keep-alive" (I think because it's my version HTTP/1.1 persistent connection), but it didn't work. And I also try to create a loop on the "req = connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')" to see what the first connection client send after it has send the GET request for .html file and it continuously send the NULL string (""). And the code line I quote here from the page is just to illustrate for my code. Hope everyone will help me with this problem.

Comment: In short: you cannot force a HTTP client to use the same connection for multiple requests. HTTP keep-alive does not enforce multiple requests over a single connection, it just allows it.

Comment: So it means there 'no way to send multiple request on the same connection, right sir? My teacher requires that in the socket programming project.

Comment: Nothing in the HTTP protocol enforces the client to only use a single connection for HTTP/1. If you control the client yourself (i.e. not a browser but your own program) then you might make the client to only use a single connection - but that's not forced by the server but by you coding the client this way. And what I said is only true for HTTP/1. You can do your own application protocol and define your own semantics, which behave as you want them to. But this is then not HTTP/1.

Comment: Does HTTP/1.1 behave my way, because my current version is HTTP/1.1, or can I turn into HTTP/2. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid because I think that HTTP/1.1 is different from HTTP/1 and I  can make it behave as I want.

Comment: HTTP/1 is short for HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1, i.e. in contrast to HTTP/2 and HTTP/3. *" I can make it behave as I want."* - You can only do this if you control both client and server, but you cannot enforce an arbitrary client to use HTTP keep-alive from the server, nor can you enforce HTTP-keeplive in a server by a client.